# Deconstructing Scalaz <**>

Tags: scala, scalaz

Can someone with better knowledge help me understand how Scalaz `<**>` and `co.` works ? I'm new to Scalaz and little bit lost in exploring.

What I want to do is accumulate errors within List something like
`(v0 <**> v1) foldLeft(l: List[Validation[A,B]) (_ :: _ :: l)`

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I found that liftFailNel helps (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/ExampleValidation.scala) but still I don't grasp all the magic that happens here.